# Display looks a bit washed out, blacks look almost gray and colors not very vibrant

Tags: display, xrandr

I've been using Ubuntu for a while now and I like it a lot, and I'm definitely not switching back to Windows. However, the thing that has bugged me is that the display on my Ubuntu install aren't as vibrant as my Windows, and looks very washed out. The blacks aren't as dark and the whites are kind of flat and not very bright.

I've also looked up this issue online and found the fix:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --set "Broadcast RGB" "Full"
```

But get this output:

```
  X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  11 (RRQueryOutputProperty)
  Serial number of failed request:  40
  Current serial number in output stream:  40
```

If it matters, I'm using an AMD Radeon RX 5500 and MSI G271 monitor. I'm also on Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks!

Comment: I remember when I first started Ubuntu I had the same issues. I don't remember what I did to fix it but this might help: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/color.html.en